# How to update time for each data received in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, time

I am a beginner in python and I am writing a script to save time for a data received from an algorithm

In the script I have an algorithm which accepts few parameters and returns the id of the data it detected. Below are few of its output:

```
S.No    Data Id         Time
1       0               2018-11-16 15:00:00
2       0, 1            2018-11-16 15:00:02
3       0, 1            2018-11-16 15:00:03
4       0, 1, 2         2018-11-16 15:00:05
5       0, 1, 2         2018-11-16 15:00:06
6       0, 2            2018-11-16 15:00:08
```

From the above output, we can see that at 1st attempt it detected data of id `0`. In the 2nd attempt it detected the data of id `1` so total data id detected `0, 1`. In 4th attempt, it detected `2` id. This keeps on going as it is running in `while True`. From above we can say that the time period for `0` id is `8 sec`, for `1` time period is `4 sec` and for `2` it is `3 sec`. I need to calculate these time periods. For this I have written below code:

```
data_dict = {}       # To store value of time for each data id
data_dict_sec = {}   # To store value of seconds for each data id

data = amc_data_retention()   # data contains the data id

for dataID in data.items():
    if run_once:
        run_once = False
        data_dict[dataID] = time.time()
        data_dict_sec[dataID] = 0     


for dataID in data.items():
    if dataID in data_dict:
        sec = time.time() - data_dict[dataID]
        data_dict_sec[dataID] += sec
        data_dict[dataID] = time.time()

    else:
        print("New data detected")
```

The first `for` loop run once and it saves the value of time of `dataID` in `dict`. In the next for loop, that time is subtracted with current time and total seconds are saved in `data_dict_sec`. In first iteration, total seconds will be 0 but from the next iteration, it will start saving the correct seconds. This works fine only if there is 1 data id. As soon as 2nd data comes, it do not record time for it.

Can anyone please suggest a good way of writing this. Main objective is to keep saving the values of time period for each data id. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time this adds `data_ID` keys to the `data_dict` is in the first run.  It should add each new `data_ID` is sees.  I'm not seeing that the first for-loop is needed, where it only adds `data_ID` keys in the first run.  It may do what you need if you moved the dictionary key initialization into the second for-loop where it checks if the `data_ID` is in the `data_dict`.  If it isn't, then initialize it.

Perhaps this would do what you need:

```
data_dict = {}       # To store value of time for each data id
data_dict_sec = {}   # To store value of seconds for each data id

data = amc_data_retention()   # data contains the data id

for dataID in data.items():
    if dataID in data_dict:
        sec = time.time() - data_dict[dataID]
        data_dict_sec[dataID] += sec
        data_dict[dataID] = time.time()

    else:
        print("New data detected")
        data_dict[dataID] = time.time()
        data_dict_sec[dataID] = 0
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. It worked. I dont know why I didnt thought in that way. Just a quick question how much `key:values` a dict can save and when we should clear it. Thanks

Comment: There's no size limit for a dict.  However, if a `data_ID` is not seen at a timestep, do you need to reset the `data_dict_sec[dataID]` back to zero for the next time it's seen?

Comment: I don't think `data_ID` is  repeated in the algorithm so no need to reset `data_dict_sec[dataID]` back to zero. However I think I it would be good to reset the complete `data_dict_sec` and `data_dict` after every hour so that it dont buffer up too much data. What do you suggest.?

Comment: If the `dataID` won't be seen again once it's gone, you could just remove any `dataID` keys from `data_dict` and `data_dict_sec` that aren't in the new `data.items()`.  You can delete them with `del`, for example `del data_dict[dataID]`.  This will keep the dictionaries clean.